# MVC4 - Using Facebook account (not for login)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application and I want to create a possibility for my registered users for post to their own Facebook wall or create events, etc.
I dont want to users can register to my site with their Facebook account just want to let them to attach the Facebook profile and when they are logged in to my site can post to Facebook.
How can I do that ?
I found solutions just for Facebook login.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (especially the [`FB.ui`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) object). Or maybe the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/).

The Javascript SDK doesn't take much back end support and allows users to do simple tasks like posting on someone's feed, or sending a request. But creating an event on Facebook would be something you'd need to use the Graph API for. That API is a backend API that allows you to create/upload/delete nearly every object type in Facebook (events, posts, albums, photos, etc).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I'm new on this topic, so sorry for the stupid question, but how can I implement the Graph API? I have to download it or the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @Gabor85 The API itself is just a set of HTTP end points which you can use a simple `WebClient` to use it. There probably are SDK's out there that you could use to make managing it easier to. Maybe search Google for "Facebook graph SDK c#" and see where that leads you.